# How can I parse the value of Content-Type from an HTTP header response?

Tags: python, python-requests, mime-types, content-type

My application makes numerous HTTP requests. Without writing a regular expression, how do I parse `Content-Type` header values?  For example:

```
text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

For context, here is my code for getting stuff in the Internet:

```
from requests import head

foo = head("http://www.example.com")
```

The output I am expecting is similar to what the methods do in [mimetools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/mimetools.html#additional-methods-of-message-objects). For example:

```
x = magic("text/html; charset=UTF-8")
```

Will output:

```
x.getparam('charset')  # UTF-8
x.getmaintype()  # text
x.getsubtype()  # HTML
```

Answer (score 20):

`requests` doesn't give you an interface to parse the content type, unfortunately, and the standard library on this stuff is a bit of a mess. So I see two options:

**Option 1**: Go use the [python-mimeparse](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-mimeparse) third-party library.

**Option 2**: To separate the mime type from options like `charset`, you can use the same technique that `requests` uses to parse type/encoding internally: use `cgi.parse_header`.

```
response = requests.head('http://example.com')
mimetype, options = cgi.parse_header(response.headers['Content-Type'])
```

The rest should be simple enough to handle with a `split`:

```
maintype, subtype = mimetype.split('/')
```

**Update:** As of Mar 2023, the current official way of doing this, now that `cgi` is deprecated, is using `email.message.Message`. See Philip Couling's answer. I agree with Philip that it's kind of gross.

Comment: Don't have the time ATM to write another answer, but [the `cgi` package has been deprecated](https://peps.python.org/pep-0594/#cgi).  Those deprecation notes detail a way to parse headers that isn't deprecated.

Comment: Looks like python-mimeparse is somehow wrapping `cgi` as well.

Answer (score 6):

**Python has this builtin.**  It's in the `email` module.

MIME and mime types are an email standard  which have been adopted in other contexts:  "**M**ultipurpose **I**nternet **M**ail **E**xtensions" (see [RFC 2045](https://ietf.org/rfc/rfc2045.html)).

The simplest way to do this reliably is to use an email parser:

```py
from email.message import Message

_CONTENT_TYPE = "content-type"

def parse_content_type(content_type: str) -> tuple[str, dict[str,str]]:
    email = Message()
    email[_CONTENT_TYPE] = content_type
    params = email.get_params()
    # The first param is the mime-type the later ones are the attributes like "charset"
    return params[0][0], dict(params[1:])
```

Answer (score 2):

Since requests 2.19.0, there is a `requests.utils._parse_content_type_header` function that splits a `Content-Type` header into a parameter-less content-type and a dictionary of parameters. This function does not split the content-type into main type and sub-type.

```
>>> requests.utils._parse_content_type_header("text/html; charset=UTF-8")
('text/html', {'charset': 'UTF-8'})
```

Note that the name of this function starts with an underscore: it’s supposed to be a private function, so I guess it might be dropped in a future release. For the record, a request to make it a public interface was rejected: https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/6362

Answer (score 2):

Building on the answer from [@philip-couling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/453851/philip-couling) we can create just a `ContentTypeHeader` object and get the MIME or Media Type as well as the parameters

```
def parse_content_type(content_type):
    from email.policy import EmailPolicy
    header = EmailPolicy.header_factory('content-type', content_type)
    return (header.content_type, dict(header.params))
```

Comment: I like this one better, as it just creates a header instance rather than a full-blown email message.

Answer (score -1):

Your question is bit unclear. I assume that you are using some sort of web application framework such as Django or Flask?

Here is example how to read Content-Type using Flask:

```
from flask import Flask, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def test():
  request.headers.get('Content-Type')


if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run()
```

Comment: It seems that he's doing some sort of crawler rather than web app.

Comment: Edited version of the question now makes more sense.